# Jquery - Infinite Scroll set header ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using [jQuery Infinite](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) scroll plugin for pagination. The pagination URL is dynamic as it is returned from API. This code works till sending the Ajax request.

```
$('#stream').infinitescroll({
    navSelector     : ".paginate:last",
    nextSelector    : "a.paginate:last",
    dataType    : 'json',
    appendCallback  : false,
    path: function(path,page){
     return $("a.paginate:last").attr("href");
    }
}, function(json, opts){

});
```

But I have to set request header in the Ajax call for authentication in the server side.

How to pass request headers with the url.

Thanks,
Srikanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is no solution via [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/410#issuecomment-18339968) ,

One solution that worked is, Adding the headers to global ajax handler.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: setHeader
});

var setHeader = function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Header1', 'XXX');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Header2', 'YYY');
}
```

Cheers!